# on -webkit-app-region: drag; why the window gets automatically resized

Tags: node-webkit

I have created the below sample code in html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
 <title>Hello Node Webkit</title>
<script>
    var guia = require('nw.gui');
    var win = guia.Window.get();
    var isMaximized = false;
</script>
<style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}
</style>
 </head>
    <body>


<div style="-webkit-app-region: drag;position:absolute;height:30px;width:910px;background:grey;position:absoulte;margin:auto;right:0;left:0">
    <div id="close"  style="-webkit-app-region: no-drag;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:2px;top:2px;width:15px;height:15px;background:white">
    </div>
    <div id="max"  style="-webkit-app-region: no-drag;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:22px;top:2px;width:15px;height:15px;background:green">
    </div>
    <div id="min"  style="-webkit-app-region: no-drag;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:52px;top:2px;width:15px;height:15px;background:red">
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    document.getElementById("close").onclick=function(){

        win.close();

    }

    document.getElementById("max").onclick=function()
    {

         if (isMaximized)
         {
          isMaximized = false;
          win.unmaximize();
        }
        else
        {
          isMaximized = true;
          win.maximize();
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("min").onclick=function(){

        win.minimize();

    }
</script>
```

package.json

```
    {
    "name": "a",
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "description": "a",
    "main": "index.html",
    "window":
    {
    "frame":false,
    "toolbar":false,
    "width":910,
    "height":750,
    "max_width":1100,
    "max_height":900,
    "min_width":910,
    "min_height":750,
    "autoResize": false
    },
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT"
    }
```

After maximizing when dragging the window , size of window automatically resizes to its original size. Why this happens.

On unmaximized state dragging works fine without any window resize event.

Comment: Try removing max_width and max_height.